# VueJS - Result of a function as default value for a Prop

Tags: vue.js, uuid, vue-props, vue-class-components, vue-property-decorator

Using VueJS with class components and `vue-property-decorator` I am Trying to write a Vue Component with an `uuid` Prop that defaults to a new uuid (using npm package `uuid`) when not provided :

```
import {Component, Prop, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import * as uuid from 'uuid';

@Component
export default class BlockComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop({default: uuid.v1()}) uuid!: string;
}
```

so that when an server-provided uuid is given on instantiation, it's used on the front-end, if not, it means it's a new element and a new uuid should be generated for that component. The problem I have with this code is that I end up with multiple components spawning with the same `uuid` (but not all of them).

Comment: use a function ()=> uuid.v1()

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks ! I didn't know I could pass a function that returns a string as a default value for a string prop. I ended up doing like this : `{default: uuid.v1}` and it works

Comment: @Estradiaz care to write a short answer so that I can set this as solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#-propoptions-propoptions--constructor--constructor---decorator) you can use a constructor, so one can pass a function.

> `@Prop(options: (PropOptions | Constructor[] | Constructor) = {})`